# Cannot use jar command on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, jar, java

The jar command is not working on my box.  I have downloaded the jdk, and set the envar "Path" to include the path to the jdk \bin directory.  However, I still get that annoying message, "'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: from a new command line, type "echo %PATH%" and include the ouptut of what your path looks like.  Also include the location of where you installed the JDK.  Its likely an issue with the path not being set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think from the error message that you're using Windows?

If so, did you try it in a command prompt that you opened after changing your path using the GUI? And did you double check for typos in the path you added?

You can always try running "echo %PATH%" to check your path, and ensure your change is both showing up and error free

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that I didn't open a new window, and now I feel stupid.  :/

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the result of `env` command ? Or please launch new command prompt, then please try again if you think you configuration is Ok.