# Regarding creation of jar file

Tags: java

I want to create a jar file through command window in windows. I was observing that you must have `jar` command included in System PATH variable. You can check this by typing `"jar"` in the command prompt if it doesn't throw an error `"jar is not recognized as an internal or external command"`. In my case it is throwing the error. What path variable needs to be set for this? Is there any open source software to create a jar? Please advise.

```
javin@localhost:~/Java jar -cvf HelloWorld.jar
```

Comment: Most IDEs have an export to jar option.

Comment: @Recursed the question was about how to create one from the command line not with a build tool or ide

Comment: @JohnKane I was addressing the `are there any open source free softwares to create jar ..!!`

Comment: @DougRamsey yeah I have downloaded the jdk Man..!!

Comment: @JohnKane is there any open software Man...!1

Comment: sorry I should have read all the words...

Comment: @user1538526: Try looking at this [answer to a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6229392/716076)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). It shows how to make a jar. I suspect though that you may not have your JAVA_HOME environment variable set, or it is not on the users path that you are using. [This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) describes how to set it in windows.

Answer (score 0):

`jar` is THE open source binary to create jar... It is included with all the java JDKs.

What else do you need?

HIH
M.

Answer (score 0):

The `jar` command is the program to create the `jar` files, you don't need to find another program.

If you get an error when typing the `jar` command at the command line, the error gives you a hint as to what is missing or wrong.  You can use this information, [along with the instructions for the jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html), to fix the issus.

Answer (score 0):

the `jar` executable will be in the bin directory of the jdk install directory. Add that to your `$PATH` and it should work.